# How to test a Configuration class which depends on another Configuration class(reads properties) and other config classes in Junit?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit

I have config classes like below

this is the config class i want to test

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class ConfigA {
private Config props;
private Logger logger;

private Map<String, Object> getSomeConfig() {
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
//reading some properties using config
map.put("field1", props.getSomeField()); 
}

@Bean("beanA")
public ClassA beanA() {
return new ClassA(this.getSomeConfig();
}

}
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@RefreshScope
public class Config{

@Value("${some.prop.someField")
private String someField;

//few other properties

@Bean("beanConfig")
public ClassConfig getClassConfig(){
return new ClassConfig.Builder().credentials(new Creds() {
@Override
public String getUser() { return getUsername();}
}
}
```

```
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class Logger{

private Config config;

@Bean
public Service getService(){
return new Service(config.getSomeService());
}
}

this config is a dependency

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class ConfigB{

@AutoWired Props props;

@Bean
@ConditionalOnProperty("some.dep.prop")
public ConfigClassB configClassB() {
return new ConfigClassB(props.getDep());
}
}
```

I have my test class like this

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:app.properties")
publoc class ConfigA{

ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner().withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(ConfigB.class, RefreshAutoConfiguration.class)).withUserConfiguration(Logger.class, ConfigA.class, Config.class);

@Test
public void checkIfConfigABeanIsCreated() {
contextRunner.run(context -> {
Assert.assertNotNull(context.getBean(ConfigA.class));
});
}
```

Issue is Config class is not reading from test application properties and beans are not getting created. How to write tests for such config classes which depend on one or more config classes which reads properties file.